# Cannot add iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

I updated Xcode to 7.3 a while ago.
Then I want to add iOS9.2 simulators but cannot add with dialog :

[image: fig1]

On the other hand, I can add iOS9.3 simulators.

I've already download iOS9.2 runtime.

[image: fig2]

Please help me...

Comment: Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com and include ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this from the terminal should likely get you back in service:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

However, please do file a bug report with relevant details, so it can be further investigated.

Comment: And you're filing that radar as we speak, yes?